# AntlrWorks do not want to debug C-target code

Tags: c, antlr, antlrworks

I am trying to remote debug a grammar that has C as target. AntlrWorks
connects to the parser fine but then it just runs it to the end. I
cannot really step it nor break.

I am using AntlrWorks 1.4.2. Parser was generated with Antlr 3.2.

Any advice appreciated.

Did any body have success on debug C-target code with antlrworks?

Comment: Besides posting here on SO, you might want to try your luck on the [ANTLR mailing list](http://www.antlr.org/mailman/listinfo/antlr-interest): the creator of the C target is pretty active there (so I'd guess he has experience with debugging C generated parsers in ANTLRWorks).